# Android multiple activity instances in memory snapshot on screen rotation change

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I created a simple Blank Activity (MainActivity class) in Android Studio and ran it on my Samsung phone.  I rotated the screen several times from portrait to landscape mode.  I took a memory snapshot and discovered that there were several instances of my Activity (MainActivity class) in the snapshot.  Why are there multiple instances of the MainActivity in the memory profile?  I don't have any code that holds any references to the Main Activity like talked about AsyncTasks or Threads.

I have read the http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html documentation.  But I am curious if the multiple instances are normal operation and are gc'ed eventually to just one Activity instance.

Comment: That would be called a memory leak :)

Comment: if it's memory leak then when I press the "gc button" on the Android Studio the memory is freed by observing the memory graph.

Answer (score 1):

The HPROF viewer shows all objects resident in memory, even if the object is not reachable from any GC roots. You can tell if an Activity is leaked by inspecting the "Distance to GC Root" column of the object. If it's not reachable, it will be blank, and will be collected, at the very least, when a full GC sweep is performed. If it has a number in that column, then you can inspect the object itself to find what's holding a reference to it.

If you find a leak when it's not intended, it'd be great if you reply with what's causing the leak.